# Setting a path for require in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a folder structure like this.

- `include/`

  - `index.js`
  - `plugin/`

    - `plugin.js`
    - `helper.js`

Where:-

> include/index.js

```
//Function for mapping the path of  "require" statement in  the plugin.js file.

var mapRequirePath = function(){

    var plugins = require('./plugin/plugin');
     return plugins;
}

//Now call the plugins..
var plugin = mapRequirePath();
```

> include/plugin/plugin.js

```
    /*
       I want all four require statements to point to the same file location '/include/plugin/helper.js'

      i.e search in the same folder location for module irrespective of the '../' or '../../' present in the require statement
    */

    var helper1 = require('./helper');
    var helper2 = require('helper');
    var helper3 = require('../../helper');
    var helper4 = require('../helper');
```

I want to map the path of `require` in `plugin.js` file so that all require call should search for its module in the `same directory only`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be able to dynamically change the NODE_PATH environment variable:

```
// First take a backup:
var _NODE_PATH = process.env.NODE_PATH;
// Add /includes/plugin to the path, also note that we need to support 
//   `require('../hello.js')`. We can do that by adding /includes/plugin/a, 
//   /includes/plugin/a/b, etc.. to the list
process.env.NODE_PATH+=':/includes/plugin:/includes/plugin/a';
// Do your think...
require('./plugins/plugin');
// Restore NODE_PATH 
process.env.NODE_PATH = _NODE_PATH;
```

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore. `process.env.NODE_PATH` returns `undefined` for me. But `module.paths` returns the search paths. That can be changed, but only for a single module, I'd like for it to work for the whole app.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the NODE_PATH variable via the command line:

```
exports NODE_PATH=directoryYouWant
```

If you don't want to have to change it for every other project, you could try just dynamically changing it in you .js file:

```
var currentNodePath = process.env.NODE_PATH;
process.env.NODE_PATH = directoryYouWant;
//do stuff then change it back
process.env.NODE_PATH = currentNodePath;
```

Comment: That would change the Node path for all filesystem. I just want to change  it only  in the case of the `require` call inside `/include/plugin folder`

Comment: I see we had a similar idea :)

Answer (score 1):

If your wanna add **/foo/bar** to require:

- by editting process.env.NODE_PATH

*then your js files should reside inside /foo/bar/node_modules/*

```
process.env.NODE_PATH = '/foo/bar' + ':' + process.env.NODE_PATH;
```

- by editting module.paths

*then your js files should reside inside /foo/bar/*

```
module.paths.push('/foo/bar');
```