# Changing the modules path

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, electron

How can I change the path that `require()` uses to look for modules in?
I tried to do this:

[Setting a path for require in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722252/setting-a-path-for-require-in-node-js)

But it didn't work, as *process.env.**NODE_PATH*** is undefined.

***Edit:** I think that I misunderstood the use of **NODE_PATH**. Where can I find the code of the `require()` function?*

Answer (score 0):

What you've tried should work fine:

```
var currentNodePath = process.env.NODE_PATH;
process.env.NODE_PATH = directoryYouWant;
//do stuff then change it back
process.env.NODE_PATH = currentNodePath;
```

If you `process.env.NODE_PATH` is empty, well...either something is wrong with your node installation, or you could safely ignore it (no need to back it up, I guess).

As for *where is require() function implementation*: pulled node from github and after some search that seems to be the place: `node/lib/internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js` (in terms of `frontend` **require** function used in your JS files, internals are probably somewhere in C sources, not sure though).